# Index notation meaning

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

So if we have something like $[\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 ) : \mathbb Q ]=a$, is the value of this the actual degree of $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 ) $? Or is it the least value of the degree? So does it mean the degree is at least $a$?

Comment: This notation means that $a=4$: this is equal to the degree of the extension.

Comment: @Crostul So where does the language of "at least" come from? Say we didn't know it was $4$, and we had a minimal polynomial of this field which had degree $4$, then does that mean the degree of the field is "at least" $4$?

Comment: Yes. Do you know what is the definition of degree of a field extension $F:K$? It is defined as the dimension $\dim_K F$ as a vector space. This number has a property: any element belonging to $F$ has a minimal polynomial whose degree divides the degree of the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}]$ is the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, which in this case is equal to $4$.
As for "at least", if $F,L,K$ are fields such that $F \subseteq L \subseteq K$, then we have $$[K:F]=[K:L][L:F],$$ so that we obviously have $[K:F] \geq [L:F]$ as all terms are $\geq 1$. Which means that if you have some extension $K$ of $F$ which has a subfield $L$ which is also an extension $F$ you can say that degree of $K$ over $F$ is at least the degree of $L$ over $F$. And in particular for any $\alpha \in K$ we have $[K:F]=[K:F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F]$.

Comment: is it the same case for [K:F] $\geq$ [K:L]?

Comment: Yes, that also holds, by the same reasoning. The intuitive picture here is that when you're extending from $F$ to $K$ you're "extending" more than when you're extending from $L$ to $K$, as you have to "add" less since $L$ might already contain some elements that aren't in $F$ but which are "needed" for $K$, which is true unless $L =F$. (Note that this is just intuition, linear algebra behind it makes it rigorous)